# Definition of basis for a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a vector space $V$ over a field $F$. According to my understanding, a *basis* of $V$ is a subset of $V$ that is linearly independent and spans the space $V$. Now consider a subspace $U\subseteq V$ of $V$. Now, naturally, I would apply the same definition to a basis of $U$, but here's where im confused:

If $W\subseteq V$ is a subset with the property that $W$ is linearly independent **and** spans $U$, is $W$ then a basis for $U$? Or does $W$ **also have** to be a subset of $U$, i.e. $W \subseteq U$ for it to be considered a basis of $U$? In other words, can $W$ be a basis of $U$ without being a subset of $U$?

Comment: We use the terminology "$W$ spans $U$" for $\mathrm{span}(W)=U$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 1):

I am using the notation of your question. The statement "$W$ spans $U$" should be reserved for when $W$ is a subset of $U$, because if $W$ is not contained in $U$ then $\text{span}(W)$ is not contained in $U$ and even if $\text{span}(W)$ contains $U$, this is not what we mean when we say that $W$ spans $U$.

Anyway, the bottom line is that a basis for a vector space is a subset of that vector space. So, if $U\subseteq V$ as in your setup, a basis for $U$ is a subset of $U$ that spans and is linearly independent.

Comment: So with $W$ spans $U$ we mean that Span($W$)$=U$? Doesn't it suffice that $U$ is contained in the span of $W$? Because then we could also say that $W$ spans $U$, since every vector in $U$ is a linear combination of vectors of $W$. That's also why I'm a bit confused on the meaning when we say that a set spans another set. But thanks for your input anyways.

Comment: Think about $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Do we want to say that this spans the $x-$axis? probably not. Moreover, by your more permissive definition of spanning, this would be a basis for the $x-$axis which is not the right idea.

Comment: Well it spans $\mathbb{R}^2$, and since the x-axis, i.e. the real line, is contained in it, we could say that it certainly spans the x-axis. But I get what you mean, maybe I'm not too educated on this matter and there exist in fact concepts that deal with this issue.

Comment: Here is one good reason why you should not use the definition you propose: the size of a basis will not be well-defined. So, vector spaces will not have dimension. For instance $\{(1,0)\}$ and $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ would both be bases of the $x-$axis. We really want the dimension to be well-defined.

Comment: That's a good point. So to conclude: a subset $W\subseteq V$ is a basis for $U$ iff Span($W$)$=U$ and $W$ is linearly independent?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.